# How to serialize a subclass using DataContracts

Tags: wcf, xml-serialization, datacontract

I just started programming a WCF project and there is a serialization issue I can't seem to fix. I'm using DataContracts and DataMembers to serialize my classes to XML.

I have a class `TestResponse` that includes a property `TestParameter`. This property contains one string parameter. Also, I have a subclass of `TestParameter` called `TestParameterSubclass`. I need to serialize this subclass. These three classes look like this:

**TestResponse.cs**

```
[DataContract(Namespace = Service.defaultNamespace, Name="TestResponse")]
public class TestResponse
{
    [DataMember(Name = "TestParameter")]
    public TestParameter param { get; set; }
}
```

**TestParameter.cs**

```
[DataContract(Namespace = Service.defaultNamespace, Name="TestParameter")]
[KnownType(typeof(TestParameterSubclass))]
public class TestParameter
{
    [DataMember(Name="ParamName")]
    public string ParamName {get; set;}
}
```

**TestParameterSubclass.cs**

```
[DataContract(Name="TestParameterSubclass")]
public class TestParameterSubclass : TestParameter
{
}
```

I have an OperationContract

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(
   Method = "POST",
   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
   RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
   UriTemplate = "/calculateA")]
TestResponse CalculateA(TestRequest data);
```

and `CalculateA`

```
public TestResponse CalculateA(TestRequest request)
{
    TestResponse tr = new TestResponse();
    TestParameterSubclass parameterSubclass = new TestParameterSubclass();
    tr.param = parameterSubclass;
    tr.param.ParamName = "hai";

    return tr;
}
```

which results in

```
<TestResponse>
  <TestParameter i:type="a:TestParameterSubclass">    
    <ParamName>hai</ParamName>
  </TestParameter>
</TestResponse>
```

However, I need the XML to use the subclass name as the element name, like this

```
<TestResponse>
  <TestParameterSubclass>    
    <ParamName>hai</ParamName>
  </TestParameterSubclass>
</TestResponse>
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

(I have a similar problem with deserializing the input XML, but I think both problems are related, so fixing this would (hopefully) also fix my other problem.)